# Can you add additional properties to .NET serialized NULL values?

Tags: .net, serialization, nullable, xml-nil

In .NET, you can serialize a nullable element using XmlElement( IsNullable = true ), which results in this:

```
<SomeElement xsi:nil="true" />.
```

However, I need to be able to add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance after any field that is being nulled out.

Example:

```
<SomeElement xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the answer:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
```